# Linq to entities group by many to many

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by, linq-to-entities

I have 3 entities, with a many/many relationship:

Products -<
Products_vehicles >-
Vehicles

1 product can have many vehicles

1 vehicle can have many products

As with all many/many relationships the products_vehicles class is hidden and is shown as navigation properties on the entities by EF 
So my classes look like this:

```
public partial class product
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string part_name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<vehicle> vehicles { get; set; }

 public partial class vehicle
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string make { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<product> products { get; set; }
```

I can get the products and all related vehicles easily

I wish to group the products by the make, model of the vehicle, so my output would look something like this:

product id: 5
part_name: door
make: ford
model: focus

product id: 5
part_name: door
make: saab
model: 9-3

Is this possible?

### Update

For more clarity, here's an example:

So let's say i have a product called 'bonnet' it fits 5 different vehicles:

- Ford Focus 1.6L
- Ford Fiesta 2L
- Ford Fiesta 1.6L
- Ford Mondeo 2L
- Ford Mondeo 1.8L

Currently i'm getting 1 product with a collection of vehicles listing all 5 above.

I want them grouped by firstly the 'partname' (bonnet), secondly 'make' and thirdly 'model'. The results should be like:

```
Bonnet > Ford, Fiesta 2L

         Ford, Fiesta 1.6L

Bonnet > Ford, Mondeo 2L

         Ford, Mondeo 1.8L

Bonnet > Ford, Focus 1.6L
```

This would be very simple in SQL but i'm having a tough time getting my head around this in Linq.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: you mean, to write a query that gets all of the same product id or part_name? The expected output you showed doesn't really show a `Group By` result.

Comment: in SQL it would be grouped by:
productid, part_name, make, model
This is the type of grouping i require.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that what you want is retrieving flat records that have selected: product id, product part name, vehicle maker and vehicle model. If not, please ignore that answer.

```
return dbcontext.products.SelectMany(
    p => p.vehicles.Select(
        v => new {
            product_id = p.id,
            part_name = p.part_name,
            make = v.make,
            model = v.model
            }
        )
    );
```

If you don't want to repeat product data (which would be actually quite recommended) then you might use the following approach with nested vehicles array instead:

```
return dbcontext.products.Select(
    p => new {
        product_id = p.id,
        part_name = p.part_name,
        vehicles = p.vehicles.Select(
            v => new { make = v.make, model = v.model }
        }
    );
```

`dbcontext.products` is DbSet corresponding to products in your database; it might be called differently in your code.

Cheers~!

Comment: Thanks Alice, sorry this doesn't produce what i was after, i haven't explained it clearly, sorry, i have updated the question above with an example for clarity.